# How to bring vuetify date picker into front of other component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-good-table

I am using vuetify date picker and vue-good-table(vgt). The problem arises when I use fixed-headers in vgt and the date component is used too.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the good old z-index perhaps?

```
.v-picker {
z-index: 999
}
```